# To have or not to have enums

Tags: dynamic, enumeration

I have data stored in database tables.  With the same data I create enums.  This is duplication of work and everytime we update the database table, we have to update the enums with new values.

It there a fair solution to this?  Something like a dynamic enum?  Or how did you solve this issue in your projects?

Comment: In what language is this? C#? Java? Something else?

Comment: [Enum from db](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/851466/populate-an-enum-with-values-from-database?rq=1) and [Dynamic Enum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725043/dynamic-enum-in-c-sharp?rq=1)