# ArrayList of enums with custom attribute

Tags: java, arraylist, enums

I have enum class that describes possible tickets types and have custom atribute to keep ticketId. When I try to add some tickets to ArrayList it makes all tickets of type X have the same ticketId. Why is that and what's more important how can I solve it?

Simplified enum class:

```
public enum Ticket {
    FirstClass(0),
    PremiumClass(1),
    EconomyClass(2);

    private int elementId;
    private Long ticketId;

    Ticket(int elementId) {
        this.elementId=elementId;
    }

    public Long getTicketId() {
        return ticketId;
    }

    public void setTicketId(Long ticketId) {
        this.ticketId = ticketId;
    }
}
```

Simplified method:

```
public void myMethod() {
    ArrayList<Ticket> tickets = new ArrayList<>();
    Ticket ticket = Ticket.FirstClass;
    ticket.setTicketId(1L);
    tickets.add(ticket);
    ticket = Ticket.FirstClass;
    ticket.setTicketId(2L);
    tickets.add(ticket);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because there is only one instance for every enum constant. Calling Ticket.FirstClass will fetch **the same** instance every time. So you are adding the same object to the list twice.

Answer (score 0):

There is really only one instance of `Ticket.FirstClass`, and there will only ever be one instance.

What you really have isn't a `Ticket`, but a `TicketType`.  You should have a separate class for `Ticket`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use enums for dynamic values,see sonar's ["enum" fields should not be publicly mutable](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/d3eb9295131104fcda5871f919fd905534b15417/java-checks/src/main/resources/org/sonar/l10n/java/rules/squid/S3066_java.html)

> enums are generally thought of as constant, but an enum with a public field or public setter is not only non-constant, but also vulnerable to malicious code.

See [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53628583/enum-represent-database-table) of making enum dynamic by making it implement an interface

Answer (score 0):

`FirstClass` is an instance of `Ticket` so when you're calling it, it's always the same one, you take the reference to the same object.

What you would need is a model with a `Ticket` and a `TicketType`

```
enum TicketType {
    FirstClass,
    PremiumClass,
    EconomyClass
}

class Ticket {
    private TicketType type;
    private Long ticketId;

    Ticket(TicketType type, long ticketId) {
        this.type = type;
        this.ticketId = ticketId;
    }
}
// ---------------------------------------------------------
// And
public void myMethod() {
    ArrayList<Ticket> tickets = new ArrayList<>();

    Ticket ticket = new Ticket(TicketType.FirstClass, 1L);
    tickets.add(ticket);

    ticket = new Ticket(TicketType.FirstClass, 2L);
    tickets.add(ticket);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing different from other answers, just to add some colors.[image: Reference in list]
When you obtain firstClass you actually are getting same object, and adding that again.

Answer (score 0):

Each `enum` value (you have got three) exists only once and each time you are using one of them you are just reusing one of those three values by creating a reference, there are no copies.

This means if you change the `ticketId` on the `FirstClass` value, it is changed wherever that value is referenced.

It seems you want to model a little ticket system. Each object having an own identity should be modeled as a `class` which has a property for the type and the id:

```
public class Ticket {
    private Long ticketId;
    private TicketType type;

    public Long getTicketId() {
        return ticketId;
    }

    public void setTicketId(Long ticketId) {
        this.ticketId = ticketId;
    }

    public TicketType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(TicketType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}

public enum TicketType {
    FirstClass(0),
    PremiumClass(1),
    EconomyClass(2);

    private final int elementId;

    Ticket(int elementId) {
        this.elementId = elementId;
    }

    public int getElementId() {
        return elementId;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it this way:

```
public void myMethod() {
    ArrayList<Ticket> tickets = new ArrayList<>();
    Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
    ticket.setType(TicketType.FirstClass);
    ticket.setTicketId(1L);
    tickets.add(ticket);

    ticket = new Ticket();
    ticket.setType(TicketType.FirstClass);
    ticket.setTicketId(2L);
    tickets.add(ticket);
}
```

I don't know why you need an `elementId` on the ticket type, that's why I just left it there (without using it). Probably you should rename `ticketId` to just `id` to keep it simple.

If the ticket's `type` or `ticketId` are never changed after assigning them you may want to remove the setters and assign the values in the constructor of `Ticket` (and make the attributes `final`).

Even if it's ok that they are changeable, you may introduce such a constructor to have code which is better readable:

In Ticket.java:

```
public Ticket(Long ticketId, TicketType type) {
    this.ticketId = ticketId;
    this.type = type;
}
```

Then you can write:

```
tickets.add(new Ticket(1L, TicketType.FirstClass));
```

If ticket is a persisted entity (which gets inspected by a framework like Hibernate) you might have to keep a no-args constructor to make it instantiable when loading it from a database.