# Set Java Enum Values from SQL String

Tags: java, enumeration

So lets say I have a sql table called "names" that has the following columns:
`NAME, X, X, X`
Lets say I now make a enum class:

```java
public enum Names {
   //I want all the `Name` values in the `Names` table to be the enum values
}
```

so if I have 3 name columns in my `Names` table called `Bob, Nick, Jamie` those names would become the enum values so I can call something like `Names.NAME`.

Thanks.

Comment: `No. Enums are always fixed at compile-time. The only way you could do this would be to dyamically generate the relevant bytecode.` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851466/populate-an-enum-with-values-from-database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating Enums Dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467215/generating-enums-dynamically)