# SEO Optimalization performance , which method ? (ASP.NET Routing)

Tags: asp.net, performance, routes

I'm trying to figure out which type of seo i will use for my site. I'm using asp.net routing (webforms) with an sql 2005 database.

I want to show my urls like:
http://www.domain.com/article-category/article-title-of-current-page

This means I need to query my category and article by it's title (well, systemtitle column). The systemtitles columns are an indexed varchar(255) column.

Does anyone have done this the similar way and if so, did u notice any performance decrease by using this method? I can always opt-in for the /2-article-category/243-article-title-of-current-page and then query by id but I was hoping to avoid that so the urls look really clean.

I've read some things about this topic before and some say the performance impact is very little when the columns are indexed while others say it will make a huge impact. For now it's not important but if the site grows it should not suffer too much from it.

Any tips/advice is welcome.

Thank you for your time.

Kind regards,
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think its somthing to worry about, a query on "where Title = 'abc'" wont be hugley differant to a query on 'where ID = x'

However, I'd advise not using LIKE as that may hinder performance.

Check this out.

[SQL SELECT speed int vs varchar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346920/sql-select-speed-int-vs-varchar)

Edit: While the above is true, I really dont think its going to be a problem. We are talking such small amounts of time on decent hardware.

Infact I'm working on some benchmarks now.

Comment: Hi Pino, Thank you for your reply. I won't be using LIKE, just selecting for a perfect hit. I'm just wondering wether the 255 varchar colum vs an int column makes a big difference. I have got it indexed though. Thanks

Comment: @Mark Check the link in the post - Updated.

Comment: Hi Pino, Thank you for the help. I will go for the select by title method maybe its a fraction slower but I like the advantage of the url structure without id. Thanks !