# Is a text column with a small number of distinct values a bad smell?

Tags: sql, sqlite, optimization, database-design

For example, let's say I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE people (
    firstname TEXT,
    lastname TEXT,
    weight FLOAT,
    zodiac_sign TEXT    
);
```

The first three columns are going to have many distinct values, and the number of them will grow without bound as I add more rows. But `zodiac_sign` will always be one of 12 values.

I'm assuming that SQLite will use 11 bytes for every instance of `'sagittarius'` (i.e. that it's not smart enough to infer that `zodiac_sign` is basically an enum that can be stored in a single byte).

Does this suggest that, if the number of rows I'll be dealing with is non-trivial, I should split off another table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE people (
    firstname TEXT,
    lastname TEXT,
    weight FLOAT,
    zodiac_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES zodiac_signs(zodiac_id)
);

CREATE TABLE zodiac_signs (
    zodiac_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT
);
```

And would this still be a good practice for a text column that holds a small number of distinct values but which isn't constrained to some set of values that will never change? e.g. if I had a column for country of birth.

Comment: Yes, that's generally the accepted and "correct" way of doing things.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between storing integer or string in database table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064743/difference-between-storing-integer-or-string-in-database-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first table design, the field `zodiac_sign` could just as well be renamed `enter_anything_you_want`. Good data integrity practices demand that the domain of each field be constrained whenever it is meaningful. For example, for general use, a `birthdate` field may be constrained only to be in the past, never in the future. For a DMV database, the same field may be constrained to be at least 16 years in the past.

When the field is text with a fixed number of valid alternatives, you could define it with a check constraint:

```
zodiac_sign text (check zodiac_sign in( 'Leo', 'Cancer', ... )),
```

(The examples I give may not directly translate into SQLite code. But I wanted to make this a more general discussion.)

However, this is somewhat awkward and would have to be repeated in every table containing that field. Meaning that should the list ever change, there could be a lot of `alter table` commands needed to update the new list. Although it may seem obvious that zodiac signs are not likely to change, that is not generally a dependable aspect of such fields.

Implementing a lookup table of the textual values, giving them a key value for foreign key reference is a much better way. It limits the valid values just like a check constraint, but all the values are in one location so changes are localized. Plus, additional fields could be added.

```
create table Zodiac(
    ID        integer not null,
    Name      text    not null,
    StartDate date,
    EndDate   date,
    constraint PK_Zodiac primary key( ID )
);
```

The dates would make calculating which sign to associate with a given date a lot easier. (Yes, Sqlite does not have a native Date datatype -- use whatever type is already your preference.)