# Mysql IN(VARCHAR) vs IN(INT)

Tags: mysql, int, varchar

I need to choose between `VARCHAR` and `INT` in a **many to many relationship**

Is it faster to do `IN('1','21','311')` or `IN(1,21,311)` in **Mysql**?

Comment: In general mysql is faster when working with integers.

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346920/sql-select-speed-int-vs-varchar

Comment: Don't use `IN()` by identifying a relation at all. Use `EXISTS()`. In any case, use foreign key id's (integers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use integers whenever possible since their representation is fixed length, four bytes by default, and comparisons are done with a single operation. Indexing and comparing strings is always more expensive, but the longer the strings get, the bigger the difference.

In your example here, which uses trivially small numbers, they might perform about the same. With real-world numbers that have six or seven digits, though, you'll see a much bigger difference.

Comment: Thanks, and what about the difference between **IN** and **EXISTS** previously mentioned by DanFromGermany in the comments?

Comment: I've only seen `EXISTS` used with [subqueries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html), not fixed lists.