# Do I need an index on primary key if I want to return reverse order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a frequently used query where `User` model `has_many :payments`:

```
current_user.payments.where(status: "succeeded").order(id: :desc).page(params[:page]).per(params[:size])
```

Do I need an index on the primary key in `:desc` order?

```
add_index :payments, [:user_id, :status], order: {id: :desc})
```

Or can I omit the order?

```
add_index :payments, [:user_id, :status]
```

**Edit:**

The `page()` and `per()` in the query are from [kaminari gem](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari). Do I need additional indexes for these?

Comment: include the order in the index for improved performance, but it's not required. The Kaminari methods `per` and `page` are not attributes on the model, so they aren't indexable. And anyway `per` and `page` are just syntactic sugar for limit and offset, so indexing has no meaning.

Comment: @LesNightingill Does that mean `add_index :payments, [:user_id, :status]` would also speed up the query with ordering? Just not as much as the index with `order`?

Comment: probably! I'm not sure... if you're using mySQL, the ref is here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/order-by-optimization.html. But my suggestion would be to write a small test with a v. large number of models in the db, and time it. Or try looking at the `.explain` output for the query to see if the index is used (if it's used, performance will be better)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few pointers and maybe an answer to your question:

I see you're querying on `.where(status: "succeeded")`, is a this an [Enum](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html)? That would also make more efficient queries.

Also, why order it by `id`? It seems more logical to me to order payments by `created_at`.

Then I wonder if you have defined the relation between `users` and `payments` with an `add_reference`. This would create foreign key relations, which are also faster.

Then finally, adding an extra index is always *possible*, but it really depends on multiple things if it's going to make a difference:

PRO:

- Finding a record will become quicker when the data search becomes big (Not sure,  something like >100000 rows)

CON:

- Inserts and updates will become slightly slower (Every insert requires an extra *index table* to be updated)

Personally I would say that the default index from the `add_reference` between `users` and `payments` will suffice for a very, very long time.

Comment: Thanks, I have previously ordered by `created_at`, but I was thinking if I order by `primary key`, i could possibly skip the need to index. Are you suggesting to `add_reference` instead of adding the index myself? If I did not go with the `add_reference` index, which of the indexes that I mentioned in my post would be best for my query?

Comment: @Gijs why would an enum be faster? Are you saying that comparing integers is faster in sql than comparing strings? Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @loop an `add_reference` is always preferred because it links the two tables on a database level, reducing the chance of malformed data (like a payment without a valid user).
@LesNightingill yes, an (Tiny)Int only takes less space, so is faster to compare and retrieve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346920/sql-select-speed-int-vs-varchar