# Not save an enum value in the database, why?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Does not save an enum value in the database, I think that's it, or I do not understand, I try to save since the console shows me a data, but when I ask from the database I get another value

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(unique = true, name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="rol")
    Rol rol;



    @Column(name = "life")
    Life life;


    public User() {

    }
    }
```

i have this in the  .info, show this message "OWNER"

```
Set<User> users =new HashSet<>();
            log.info("CONSOLE"+ user.getRol());
            users.add(user);
            meet.setUsers(users);
            return meetRepository.save(meet);
```

but in swagger i get other value
ROL: PARTICIPANT

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "string2",
    "state": "pause",
    "bet": {
      "profit": 0,
      "inversion": 0
    },
    "users": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "string",
        "password": "string",
        "email": "ema",
        "rol": "PARTICIPANT",
        "life": "suspend"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: just read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229856/ways-to-save-enums-in-database

Comment: @AkshayMulgavkar sorry you should answer my question please

Comment: @AkshayMulgavkar help me please

Comment: have you check in database ? can you try to add @Enumerated(EnumType.String) on the rol field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your fields rol and life are Enums you have to declare them as Enums with `@Enumerated`. There are two options. Default will store the ordinal number. Or you can choose to use the string name to store in the DB. That's the better option in terms of maintainability:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name="rol")
Rol rol;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "life")
Life life;
```

Two remarks:

1. When the database field has the same name as the attribute you can omit @Column. And if the table has the same name as the entity this is also true for the @Table annotatoin.
2. Read more about Enums and JPA and if you really should use it in one of my articles: https://72.services/de/should-you-use-enums-with-jpa/

Answer (score 0):

When you save a Enum to the database as stated above you have the option of saving it as String or as Numerical Ordinal. The numerical option is very painfull because every time you need to update your enum values or change the order of the values you will mess with your database options for the field. Also another thing that is very painfull even when you store the strings on the database is that when you are using some ORM such as Hibernate and you have NULL values. So keep your enums as strings and avoid NULL value.