# jQuery $.each is really slow

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I am trying to build a dynamic combo box with `$.each` and `$('<OPTION>')`, but it is really slow on IE (takes 3/4 mins to render data after server response) on firefox and other browsers it's fine.

Here is my code that builds combo

```
var sel = ('#myDynCmb');
$.each(dataCollection, function(key,_value) {
    sel.append($("<OPTION>").val(key).text(_value));
});
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: any errors or misuse of jquery here?

Comment: What is the value of `dataCollection`?

Comment: it's json object (server's response), not more than 20 values in it

Comment: Doesn't have issue in this code, see this http://jsfiddle.net/rR6GQ/1/embedded/result/ (Very fast in IE8)

Comment: Have you tried a for loop. $.each _is_ slow, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887450/each-vs-for-loop-and-performance)

Answer (score 6):

Dom manipulation are usualy slow, especialy when you're appending to the dom.

One good practices is to put all your html into a var and append the content of this var to the dom, wich result in one dom opération, this is much faster

```
var htmlToAppend = "<select>";
$.each(dataCollection, function(key,_value) {
    select += "<option value="+key+">"+_value+"</option>";
});
htmlToAppend += "</select>";
$('#myDynCmb').empty().append(htmlToAppend);
```

Something like that

Answer (score 0):

It could be a rendering issue on IE (usually slow on DOM manipulation).

You can try something like this:

```
var dummyList = $("<select />");
$.each(dataCollection, function(key,_value) {
    dummyList.append($("<option />").val(key).text(_value));
});
$('#myDynCmb').empty().append(dummyList.find('option'));
```

So you load the options into a dummy list (not in DOM), then you add all the elements into you list (in DOM).

Answer (score 0):

Try all the solutions but it was still embarrassingly slow so I have to switch it to classic javascript, new option, and it's now super fast