# LinQ foreach in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I easily do these type of loops in Jquery or Javascript? Preferably without any other plugins.

```
string a = "";
foreach (var i in (from a in DbList1 select a.FieldA).Distinct())
{
   a += i + ", ";
}
```

and this

```
foreach (var i in DbList2)
{
   a += i.FieldB + ", ";
}
```

Loop number 2 could be solved like this atleast.

```
$.each(aData.DbList2, function (index, value) {
 a += value.FieldB;
);
```

Not 100% sure this is the most effective though

Comment: are you iterating upon an array and getting something from each element ? Better to post a sample question like **How to concatinate words in array ?**  Syntax from other languages are just confusing.

Comment: In the javascript, its an array inside a object

Comment: hi please find this URL that may be help to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887450/each-vs-for-loop-and-performance

Comment: a sample of your source data would go a long way to getting help on how to do something with it - I take it, since you don't want any libraries (except the biggest piece of bloat in existence, jQueery) https://linqjs.codeplex.com/ is out of the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second one is easy enough to do in vanilla JavaScript:

```
var a = "";
for (var i = 0; i < DbList2.length; i++){
    a += DbList2[i].FieldB + ", ";
}
```

First one is a little trickier, but not impossible and can also be done with vanilla JS.

```
var a = "";
var uniques = [];

for (var i = 0; i < DbList1.length; i++ ){
    var fieldA = DbList1[i].FieldA;
    // check if we've already seen this value
    if (uniques.indexOf(fieldA) < 0)
    {
        // Nope, record it for future use
        uniques.push(fieldA)

        // and update the string.
        a += fieldA + ", ";
    }
}
```

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887450/each-vs-for-loop-and-performance this seems to be very good performace. So is it an easy way to only add unique values to a?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) method for iterating array variable.

Code snippets:

```
var arr = jQuery.map( aData.DbList2, function(value) {
return value.FieldB;
});
//To get unique array variable
var uniqueArr = [];
$.each(arr, function (i, el) {
            if ($.inArray(el, uniqueArr) === -1) uniqueArr.push(el);
        });
```

Comment: how do you emulate the Distinct() function :p

Comment: Yea, how can Distinct or Unique as I read it's called in Jquery be implemented?