# kendo DataSource at() method for large dataSets. browser crashing

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-datasource, kendo-listview

I am trying to select some users (about 200) from a list of 2000 users and load it onto another div but every time the loop runs it opens the following dialog in Firefox

***A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue.***

It works on smaller lists though. Is there any optimized way to achieve this? Below is my code:

```
var usersList = $("#UsersList").data("kendoListView");
var usersListDS = usersList.dataSource;
var newSelectedUsers = usersList.select();
var selectedUsersData = [];

$.each(newSelectedUsers, function (index, data) {
    var itemIndex = $(data).index();
    var newItem = usersListDS.at(itemIndex);
    if (newItem) {
        selectedUsersListData.push(newItem);
        selectedUsersData.push(newItem);
    }
});
```

Comment: have you try recursiv function?

Comment: Nope.. haven't tried it @ChristianMeneux..How would that help?

Comment: it could could be more efficient, for loop is working faster than each too. You shoud have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887450/each-vs-for-loop-and-performance)

Comment: dont think that dataSource.at() causes problem, can u provide jsfiddle?