# How to break out from jQuery click event function from inside $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I exist from the **whole jquery click event function** if the condition is met inside `$.each`. One solution would be storing condition result in a variable and then have an if statement after the loop but is not there a direct way?

```
$(".main").on("click",".button",function(e){

    $(this).siblings('input').each(function(){

       if($(this).val() == 'yourvalue') {
         return false;
       }

    });


    //......rest of the code runs if the above condition is NOT met

 });
```

Comment: You can't. Use normal for loop.

Comment: Judging by the body of your callback function, seems like `array.find(x => x == 'yourvalue')` would be a better alternative.

Comment: [for-loops are up to 8x faster than $.each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887450/each-vs-for-loop-and-performance)

Comment: @dfsq: Yes you can. You're thinking of the native `forEach`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784780/how-to-break-out-of-jquery-each-loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to break out of jQuery each Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784780/how-to-break-out-of-jquery-each-loop)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Haha, this is funny. Indeed you need to return false.

Comment: After your edit your `this` is — not — what you think it is. You want to put it in a variable. Before your `each` `function`.

Comment: @AjAX.: What makes you think it isn't what the OP expects? They're looking for sibling inputs, then using `val`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Is the second `this` — not — the `window`?

Comment: @AjAX.: Correct, it is not. `$(this).siblings('input').each(...)` will call its callback once for each sibling input, with `this` referring to the input. http://api.jquery.com/each/ (An early version of the question used [the other `each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) but didn't use `this` in the callback, and `this` would have referred to each element.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to break out from jQuery click event function from inside $.each

So you want to `return false` from the `click` handler based on the result of the inner loop. You have several options:

1. Use a simple `for` loop [as in your answer]
2. Use [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) to get an array for the inputs, and use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

   ```
   $(".main").on("click", ".button", function(e) {
       if ($(this).siblings('input').get().some(function(input) { return input.value == 'yourvalue'; })) {
           return false;
       }

       //...
   });
   ```

   which is more concise with an ES2015+ arrow function:

   ```
   $(".main").on("click", ".button", function(e) {
       if ($(this).siblings('input').get().some(input => input.value == 'yourvalue')) {
           return false;
       }

       //...
   });
   ```
3. Use a flag outside the loop:

   ```
   $(".main").on("click", ".button", function(e) {
       var flag = false;
       $(this).siblings('input').each(function() {
           if ($(this).val() == 'yourvalue') { // can use this.value instead of $(this).val() here
               flag = true;
               return false; // Breaks the `each` loop
           }
       });
       if (flag) {
           return false;
       }

       //...
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

What you have should work. To break a $.each loop, you simply need to return false.

Returning true skips to the next iteration, equivalent to a continue in a normal loop.

```
$(".main").on("click",".button",function(e){

    $.each(array, function(i){

       if(i === 'yourvalue') {
         return false; // will exit the $.each loop
       }

    });

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting to native loop will enable me to exist the click function when using `return false`

```
$(".main").on("click",".button",function(e){

   var inputs = $(this).siblings('input')

   for(var x = 0; x < inputs.length; x++){

     if(inputs.eq(x).val() == 'yourvalue') {
       return false;
     }

   }


//......rest of the code runs if the above condition is NOT met

});
```

Answer (score -1):

jQuery doc: "We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next iteration."