# Random numbers for array, but not the same | JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create an array of numbers. The array should look like the following:

`[1, 2, 1]` or `[2, 1, 2]`

I don't want the same number again after it's already been chosen.

So I don't want `[1, 1, 2]` or `[2, 2, 1]`

I have the following code:

```
var chosenHosts = [];

for (var i = 0; i < match.match_games; ++i) {
     var num = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);

     chosenHosts.push(num);
}

console.log(chosenHosts);
```

This code pushes the same number twice. Does anyone have an idea on how to achieve as described above?

P.S. Sorry for the confusing title, I didn't know how else to describe it.

Comment: there is no jquery in your code

Comment: @depperm Yes, sorry about that. I meant, using JQuery is also fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this will work

```
var chosenHosts = [1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)];

for (var i = 1; i <  match.match_games; i++) {
     var num = chosenHosts[i - 1] == 1 ? 2 : 1; 
     chosenHosts.push(num);
}

console.log(chosenHosts);
```

Comment: this will only work if the random numbers are between 1 or 2

Comment: True - like OP asked for @depperm

Comment: @baao That's almost what I need! This outputs 4 numbers. I only need 3. Do you have any idea on how to achieve that?

Comment: So your match.match_games always holds 3 entries? @Chris

Comment: @baao It varies between 1 or 3

Comment: @Chris change `for` condition to `i < match.match_games-1;`

Comment: Ok, changed it @Chris - now it does exactly what you want

Comment: @Chris, same approach, different code: `for(var chosenHosts = [], num = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random()*2); chosenHosts.length < match.match_games; num = 1+(num&1))
  chosenHosts.push(num);`

Comment: @Thomas have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183201/should-a-developer-aim-for-readability-or-performance-first. Micro optimization over readability is never a good idea!

Comment: Another possible way of streamlining that strikes me as more readable: `var chosenHosts = Math.random() < 0.5 ? [1, 2, 1] ? [2, 1, 2]; chosenHosts = chosenHosts.slice(0, match.match_games);`   Depending on how the array is consumed, you might not even need to bother with the second line.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the last element in the array and continue creating a random number until it's different.

```
var chosenHosts = [1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)];

for (var i = 0; i < match.match_games; i++) {
  var r = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
  while (chosenHosts[i] == r)
    r = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
  chosenHosts.push(r);
}

console.log(chosenHosts);
```